# Modern Directions to Sambatyon River

Tags: sources-mekorot, geography

A Rav recently mentioned a sefer was written by an American Rav in the 1930s called Kol Mevaser which provided exact directions to find the [Sambatyon River](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/sambatyon). (The map began in Tibet and carefully explained to travel 1 ½ days by donkey from one city, then follow North a certain amount of time to find the river.) Does anyone know who authored this sefer and/or have a copy of this particular work's directions?

Comment: Your question header asks for Gan Eden, but your actual question is for the Sambatyon? Are you implying they are the same thing?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/20732

Comment: Ditto @DavidKenner’s q. Also, FWIW, the main focus of his book (R. Shimon Horowitz) is his quest for the Lost Tribes. Google his name and “lost tribes”; later research in the field discuss him and his travels.